# Android webview кнопка назад

Tags: java, android, webview

подскажите в чем проблема, не работает кнопка назад в приложении

```
    public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
 
    public WebView mWebView;
 
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
        mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webViewT1);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Maps/web/map.html");
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
 
 
        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 
        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
 
        return v;
    }
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну потому что у фрагмента нет метода onBackPressed соответственно вы ничего не переопределяете, По факту вы просто создали метод, который нигде не вызывается.

Comment: @AVRamones подскажите как правильно реализовать кнопку "назад"
фрагментов несколько и каждый открывает разный webview

Comment: Посмотрите тут, выберите что-то исходя из своих потребностей.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решил проблему с помощью setOnKeyListener

```
mWebview.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                    && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                    && mWebview.canGoBack())
            {
                mWebview.goBack();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

получилось так

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebStorage;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    public static WebView mWebView;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
        mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webViewT1);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Maps/web/map.html");
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        mWebView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                        && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                        && mWebView.canGoBack())
                {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
        WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData();

        // Clear all the cookies
        CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
        CookieManager.getInstance().flush();

        mWebView.clearCache(true);
        mWebView.clearFormData();
        mWebView.clearHistory();
        mWebView.clearSslPreferences();

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        return v;
    }

}
```

может кому пригодится